# Combining ModelChoiceFields in a Djano form to save in a single ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` where I want to combine a series of `ModelChoiceFields` into a single ManyToMany field when I save to the database.

So my model form is something like:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fulltime = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = Type.objects.filter(tag_type=jb_models.F_PTIME),
    )
    optional = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = Type.objects.filter(tag_type=jb_models.OPTIONAL),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('jobtype', 'title', \
            'fulltime','optional')
        widgets = {
            'jobtype': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':50}),
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        instance.jobtype.set(self.cleaned_data['fulltime'])
        instance.jobtype.add(self.cleaned_data['optional'])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

This gives me the TypeError  object is not iterable.  How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument of `set()` method should be list of objects, so you can wrap your object with `[]`:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super().save()
    instance.jobtype.set([self.cleaned_data['fulltime']])
    instance.jobtype.add(self.cleaned_data['optional'])
    return instance
```

Also note you should save `instance` before set it's manytomany relations, otherwise you'll get error:

> ValueError: 'Job' instance needs to have a primary key value
>   before a many-to-many relationship can be used.

Check this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).